# Abnormal behaviour when exiting function with ESC key while using base::readline

Tags: r, loops, input, user-input

I am using a loop that populate a vector. At one point I ask for user input using `base::readline` that is located *before* the vector affectation. **If I escape** using ESC key during the command prompt the affectation is still done, even though it happens after this command prompt.

For instance I would run :

```
v1 <- character(1)

for (i in 1) {
  message(i)
  if (i == 1) {
    user_input <- readline("say something: ")
  }
  v1[i] <- i
}
```

and I would escape using ESC key when the console is prompting "say something". Then the vector value would be :

```
> v1
[1] "1"
```

while it should be `""` since I interrupt the flow before the affectation.

My initial guess was that R still execute the other statement before exiting the loop. Though, when I add a print/message statement right before the affectation, the later is not executed when I escape using ESC key. For instance when I execute the following statement

```
v2 <- character(1)

for (i in 1) {
  message(i)
  if (i == 1) {
    user_input <- readline("say something: ")
  }
  message("before affectation")
  v2[i] <- i
}
```

and I use ESC key at command prompt the message `"before affectation"` is not displayed. Even more curious: the affectation to the vector is not done (that is the value of v2 is `""` as it should be).

Also, when I add a function that has no side effects (i.e not print/message/etc.) before the affectation, then the affectation is made.

I cannot make sense of these differences in behaviour. The header of my session info is :

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```